# How to add the data coming from the datasource in the same row of the input data C#?

Tags: c#

I hope I can explain this better but here is my dilemma.
When my form loads, it loads the employee name from my datasource in my combo box. I have two input text box for week and hours worked.

How it should work after clicking the Add button:
-dgv should populate the emp id in the column I created for the employee id, same with the name currently selected in the form as well as the week and the hours worked. However, it doesn't work that way because I am not sure how to add the Employee id that I should be getting from the datasource to the row I am creating when clicking Add. Please see below image.

[image]

Here is my code on the add button

Boolean blnsOK = true;
            Decimal decValue = 0M;

```
        lblError.Text = "";

        //**Verify Payrate field is numeric.
        try
        {
            decValue = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPayrate.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Hours worked must be a numeric value";
            blnsOK = false;
        }
        if (blnsOK)
        {
```

//I am not sure what to put before the cboEmployee.text to pull the employee id from the datasource.
                dtPay.Rows.Add(cboEmployee.Text,txtWeek.Text, txtPayrate.Text, decValue.ToString("N2"));
                txtPayrate.Text = "";
            }

Below is my code to display employees on form load.

lblError.Text = "";

```
        dsData = clsDataBase.GetEmployeeNames();
        if (dsData == null)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error retrieving employee names";
        }
        else if (dsData.Tables.Count < 1)
        {
            lblError.Text = "Error retrieving employee names";
            dsData.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            cboEmployee.DataSource = dsData.Tables[0];
            cboEmployee.DisplayMember = "FullName";

        }
```

Below is my code to get the data from the database

```
 public static DataSet GetEmployeeNames()
    {
        SqlConnection cnSQL;
        SqlCommand cmdSQL;
        SqlDataAdapter daSQL;
        DataSet dsSQL = null;
        Boolean blnErrorOccured = false;

        cnSQL = AcquireConnection();
        if (cnSQL == null)
        {
            blnErrorOccured = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //**Build command to execute stored procedure
            cmdSQL = new SqlCommand();
            cmdSQL.Connection = cnSQL;
            cmdSQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmdSQL.CommandText = "GetEmployeeNames";

            cmdSQL.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ErrCode", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmdSQL.Parameters["@ErrCode"].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

            dsSQL = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                daSQL = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdSQL);
                daSQL.Fill(dsSQL);
                daSQL.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                blnErrorOccured = true;
                dsSQL.Dispose();
            }
            finally
            {
                cmdSQL.Parameters.Clear();
                cmdSQL.Dispose();
                cnSQL.Close();
                cnSQL.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

I appreciate your assistance and your patience.

Comment: U just want to add the rows  u are getting from the datasource to the dgv  ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for the quick response. Yes and no, the employee id and the employee names are from the datasource, the employee name is automatically filled in when the form loads. However, when I click the Add button, my dgv should also display the employee id from the datasource (where my employee name is being pulled from).

Comment: Check my answer and let me know if it helped :)

Comment: It is unclear what is coming from the database. Does the database “contain” a table to hold the employee hours worked? In other words, if the employee opens the program, selects his name from the combo box, enters some hours worked then clicks the “Add” button… where are you saving this info?

Comment: Hi Zack, for some reason my code didn't complete paste in the site, but here is how I add my data in the dgv :  

if (blnsOK)
            {
                dtPay.Rows.Add(cboEmployee.Text,txtWeek.Text, txtPayrate.Text, decValue.ToString("N2"));
                txtPayrate.Text = "";
            }

Comment: Hi John, the database contains the name and the employee id but the week and hours worked are not in the database. The form if to enter payroll data. User should select the name of the employee from the cbo and type in the week and the hours worked. When user clicks the add button, dgv should show the empID, name, week and hours worked.

Comment: Therefore, the employee/company has no need to “save” this info. Meaning, the data would have to be input again next time you run the program. Do you plan to save this info, because it will make a difference since you may not necessarily want an employee to change the hours worked, after they have already been posted? In addition, when the form loads, it would be handy to display the hours worked from “previous” dates. Just a thought.

Comment: Hi John, what you recommended makes a lot of sense, however, I am working on a school project and the instructor has specific requirements for this project. When the form loads, it displays the employee name only, user will key in week and hours work and when user clicks add, dgv should display the empId too with the hours work, name and week but will not allow to duplicate for the same week.

Comment: When the user selects another Employee from the cbo, the user will have to enter the hours of work for that specific employee. This is like a manual payroll input where weekly, Payroll dept will have to enter every employees hours of work. After each click of Add button, the hours worked is cleared. Currently, I am just trying to show the employee id in the first cell of the row and that emp id is coming from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> add the Employee id that I should be getting from the datasource to the row I am creating when clicking Add

I don't see where you are adding rows to your `DataGridView`...However,it seems like you are filtering the data of your database and you just want to display the filtered data,am i correct ?

It is really unclear of what you want but here's a full example of what i understand of ur wants :

```
string column1;
string column2;
string column3;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from TableName WHERE employeename='" + employee.Text + "'", connectionString);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader;
while (dr.read)
{

    column2 = dr(1).ToString;
    column3 = dr(2).ToString
}
 column1 = employeename.Text;
 DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
 row.Cells[0].Value = column1;
 row.Cells[1].Value = column2;
 row.Cells[2].Value = column3;
 yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: I want to display the 2 data from the datasource and add the input data as well from the form. The name (from the datasource) was added in the dgv because it appears in the cbo while employee id does not appear in dgv because it is not in the form. :(

Comment: Thanks Zack! I apologize for not being so clear. I appreciate your assistance. :)

Comment: Please accept the answer as answer and upvote it if it helped :)

Comment: Unfortunately it is not yet. Your examples where close though and gave me an idea but I am still not getting the EmpId in the first column. I'll check with my instructor and post back here. :)

Comment: As the answer helped you,can u please mark it as the answer ? I will help u in future as well

Comment: Thanks Zack! I'm sure you will! :)

Comment: Good night :)Sweet dreams

Comment: So, apparently, I had to use "cboEmployee.ValueMember = "EmpID";" when I load my employee data and used "cboEmployee.SelectedValue" when adding my row and columns. :)

Comment: Ow...Oke...Good to hear it fixed :)